# How can i make my model take 2 tensors as inputs. I have tried using a merge layer, but i didn't quite get it to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Make Training data

```
import random
import numpy as np


x_train = []
x1_train = []
y_train = []
atoms = [0,1]
p = [0.6,0.4]
for i in range(1000):
    x_train.append([np.random.choice(atoms, p=p),np.random.choice(atoms, p=p)])
for i in range(1000):
    x1_train.append([np.random.choice(atoms, p=p),np.random.choice(atoms, p=p)])
for i in x_train:
    if 1 in i:
        y_train.append([1])
    else:
        y_train.append([0])
```

Convert to numpy arrays to make them usable by keras

```
x_train = np.array(x_train)
x1_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
import tensorflow as tf
```

Normalize the data to make it better for the model to use

```
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis = 1)
x1_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis = 1)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(y_train, axis = 0)
```

Make model with dense layers

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128 , activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = tf.nn.sigmoid))
```

Compile and train model on the 3 lists

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, x1_train, y_train, epochs = 10)
```

Comment: Read about functional API models. As per definition, sequential models are supposed to be just sequential.

Comment: tensorflow has a tutorial on making models with multiple inputs and outputs https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs

Comment: Instead of using `Sequential`, try the [Functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/). To define multiple inputs, use the `Input` layer.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras

inputs1 = Input(shape=(784,))
inputs2 = Input(shape=(784,))

outputs_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs1)
outputs_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs2)

outputs = keras.layers.Concatenate([outputs_1, outputs_2])

predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(outputs)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs1,inputs2], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([data1, data2], labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras

inputs1 = Input(shape=(784,))
inputs2 = Input(shape=(784,))

outputs_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs1)
outputs_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs2)

outputs = keras.layers.Concatenate([outputs_1, outputs_2])

predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(outputs)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs1,inputs2], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([data1, data2], labels)
```

Answer by @irishabha gives following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "...\main.py", line 20, in 
> predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(outputs)
> File "...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 738, in **call**
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument:  (of type <class 'keras.src.layers.merging.concatenate.Concatenate'>)